# Counting the number of characters in a string

Tags: vba, count, character, powerpoint

I am trying to get the number of characters from a variable using the Len() funtion, but vba says it doesn't recognise it. So I am wondering what is my mistake and how can I fix it?

```
Dim y As Long
Dim counthidden As Byte
Dim nbcharac As Long
Dim espace As Long

'boucle sur toutes les diapos à partir de la 2e
For y = 3 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
Set Diapo = ActivePresentation.Slides(y)

If Diapo.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue Then
counthidden = counthidden + 1
End If
'si la diapo a un titre
If Diapo.Shapes.HasTitle And Diapo.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse Then
Set titre = Diapo.Shapes.Title
nbcharac = Len(titre)
espace = 90 - nbcharac
texte_ajout = texte_ajout & titre.TextFrame. _
TextRange.Text & space(espace) & Format(y - counthidden, "0") & vbCrLf
End If

Next y
```

Thank you in advance for your help
(and also, if you know the number of characters that can fit into a powerpoint page, though I can test for that)

Comment: what you are supposed to get by 'Chr(espace)'? . i guess you want to do `space(espace)`

Comment: @milevyo I am trying to write the number of the page of the slides (like table of contents) on the right side of the slide. I am tried the vbTab, but I dont get the numbers aligned. chr(espace) is supposed to put spaces between the titles and the page numbers (or so I thought).
The error is before that chr() / space() confusion, so it doesn't read that far. (and this version is a modification of something that worked before, the page numbers were before the titles)

Comment: I am surprised this compiled/ran.  `titre` should be a string, which means the `set` should throw an error.  I think you wanted:  `titre = Diapo.Shapes.Title` *without* the `set`

Comment: No, `titre` is not a string, it's a `Shape` object, so using `Set` is fine. However, since it is an object `Len()` will not work, you need to get the text from the shape to get the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `tietre` is a `Shape` object and not a string, `Len` will not work. You need to get the text from the shape to calculate the length, something like:

```
Set titre = Diapo.Shapes.Title
nbcharac = Len(titre.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
```

A lot of these problems can be prevented by using `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, which will force you to explicitly declare all variables, like `tietre` and `Diapo` (a `Slide` object) in your example, and show many of the problems at compile time instead of while running.

Comment: Can I do something like that but instead of getting the length, can I get the size of the string (in px or mm)?

Comment: Do you mean the font size? Or the size of the textbox?

Comment: I mean the width of the string inside the textbox. I know that "a" doesn't have the same width as "l" does. So "azerty" isn't the same width as "wwpmmm" despite them both having 6 characters. In my presentation the size of the textbox is set as the width of the slide. I don't know if Im explaining it the right way, so, sorry for that.

Comment: Instead of length being expressed in number of character, would it be possible for it to be expressed in pixels or milimeters?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't know if it is possible,

Comment: From what I gathered while searching, I don't think it is possible either (not by doing something simple). But thank you :)